# copy data from source table every 1hr from the point where it left

Tags: mysql

I am trying to come with mysql query/procedure which basically copies data( not all data and not from all fields) to another table which already exists but the fields name in this table is different that the source field. Since this sql query will be run every 1 hr through some scheduler, it needs to have a logic which should know/check the source table so that it doesn't copy the same data again. A flag would be required in source table then I think.

Table : Product Revenue date A MC 2020-10-11 B VI 2020-10-12 C MC 2020-10-12 D MC 2020-10-13

This table keeps adding records live from a front end application. So the query to copy this data after ever 1 hr has to start coping from where it left last time.

```
create table DemoTable ( 
    ClientId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ClientName varchar(20), 
    isMarried tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1 
);

INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName,isMarried) values('Larry',0); 
INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName) values('David');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName,isMarried) values('Mike',1); 
INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName) values('Carol');
```

Comment: you need a flag in main table and a `INSERT INTO table1 (a, b) SELECT col_a, col_b from table 2 WHERE flag = 0`

Comment: can you explain in little more detail please?

Comment: mysql> create table DemoTable
(
   ClientId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   ClientName varchar(20),
   isMarried tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.64 sec)
Inserting some records
mysql> INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName,isMarried) values('Larry',0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName) values('David');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName,isMarried) values('Mike',1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.19 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO DemoTable(ClientName) values('Carol');

Comment: mysql> select *from DemoTable;

This will produce the following output that displays one of the column, which is set as flag −

+----------+------------+-----------+
| ClientId | ClientName | isMarried |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1        | Larry      | 0         |
| 2        | David      | 1         |
| 3        | Mike       | 1         |
| 4        | Carol      | 1         |
+----------+------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Now this table keeps updating except that I have put the flag to get help from you on how I can leverage it..
Suppose I have coped this to another table, and this source table gets updated again with new records.. Now how I can have a sql that starts coping from where it has left last time so that there is no duplication of records...

Answer (score 0):

If your another table also store primary key(ClientID) from table `DemoTable` then you can do following without any modification in database structure.

```
Table Structure:
DemoTable - ClientID(Pk), CilentName, isMarried
DemoTable_New - Id(PK), ClientID, ClientName
```

```
INSERT INTO DemoTable_New (ClientId, ClientName) 
SELECT d.ClientId, d.ClientName
FROM DemoTable d
LEFT JOIN DemoTable_New dn ON d.ClientId = dn.ClientId  -- Make sure to do Left Join
WHERE dn.Id IS NULL;  -- Only pick for which record was not found in DemoTable_New
```

Comment: Thanks but this still not solves my issue... DemoTable has many records. Demotable_New has data but from now on needs to gets it's feed from DemoTable starting from 2020-09-15 15:30:23. Also the feed that will be taken from DemoTable is only for 3 specific fields say a,b,c .  
The script -
INSERT INTO DemoTable_New (ClientId, ClientName) 
SELECT d.ClientId, d.ClientName
FROM DemoTable d
LEFT JOIN DemoTable_New dn ON d.ClientId = dn.ClientId  -- Make sure to do Left Join
WHERE dn.Id IS NULL;  -- Only pick for which record was not found in DemoTable_New

Comment: will copy the whole data from DemoTable to DemoTable_New

Comment: First time will copy complete data but from the second run it will only copy the new data only.

Comment: Can this be done through flag ( storing flag info) , as this join query is more query intensive.